# Convert div data to a float and present it

Tags: javascript, casting, int

So what I tried to do is to get all my divs with class "value" that are in `betreturns` in my html document, these divs looks like this:

```
<div class="value">$ 0.53</div>
```

what I want my code to do is to get the total value of them all and present the result in an alert, but I have some problems with converting to a number and hoping for some help, this is how far I have come but all i get in return is **NaN**.

Code:

```
window.addEventListener("load", prep, false);
function prep() {
    var returns = document.getElementById("betreturns");
    var value =returns.getElementsByClassName("value");
    var val;
    var str;
    var total;
    for (x=0; x<value.length; x++) {
        str = value[x].toString();
        val = str.substring(2);
        val = parseFloat(val);
        total = total + val;
    }
    window.alert(total);
}
```

any ideas?

Comment: Are you sure all your `div`s are in the same format? `NaN` might be returned during the `parseFloat` function. If the first character cannot be converted to a number, NaN is returned. To check, do a `console.log(val)` inside the `for` loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to initialize your `total` variable in order to increase it.

`var total = 0;`

For accessing the div´s text, you have to get the `innerHTML` property, like

`str=value[x].innerHTML;`

Here´s a plunk with the example http://plnkr.co/edit/5S6cJDPbT7PvO0u77z8m?p=preview

Hope you find it useful

Answer (score 0):

Your variable "total" is declared but undefined. Try setting it to 0 before doing any calculations on it:

```
 var total = 0;
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: it did not work, same provlem, tried to set all vairables to values